# Collect information from different workbooks that were created after a specific date

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently using the following code to collect specific cell contents from a variety of workbooks into a tracking sheet.

```
Sub CopyRangeValues() 
    Dim basebook As Workbook 
    Dim mybook As Workbook 
    Dim FNames As String 
    Dim rnum As Long 
    Dim y As Variant 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    ChDrive "D:\" 
    ChDir "D:\" 
    FNames = Dir("Sample-*.xl*") 
    If FNames <> "" Then 
        Set basebook = ThisWorkbook 
        y = InputBox("What column should start getting the values", "Input Row Value", 2) 
        If y = "" Then Exit Sub 'cancel hit
        rnum = Val(y) 
        Do While FNames <> "" 
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FNames) 
            basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 1).Value = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("D1").Value 
            basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 2).Value = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("G1").Value 
            basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 3).Value = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C5").Value 
            basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 4).Value = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C8").Value 
            basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 5).Value = mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C9").Value 
            mybook.Close False 
            rnum = rnum + 1 
            FNames = Dir() 
        Loop 
    End If 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

I'm trying to alter the code so that I after I do the initial collection, when activated it will only collect information from workbooks that have been added since the last time it was run. Since all the workbooks have their creation date in the same cell, I was trying to make that a search criteria. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Add a column for the file name and last update date: then you can use that to determine whether to add/update info from a given file.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise people actually use Dir() etc.   I would have chosen to Windows Scripting Runtime to list the files in a folder and then loop through examining the creation date of each file.  This means I would not have to open each workbook to inspect the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the created-date is in column 6, otherwise modify accordingly.

First, declare and assign a date variable to use for the "start" date, values less than this will not be used.

```
    Dim startDate as Date
    startDate = #1/1/2014#   '<-- Modify as needed
```

And a variable for the columnn in which the date is found:

```
    Dim dateColumn as Integer
    dateColumn = 6           '<-- Modify as needed
```

Then, add some logic within your loop to so that it only processes files with a created date greater than or equal to the one you defined in `startDate` variable.

```
    Do While FNames <> "" 
        IF CDate(basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, dateColumn).Value) >= startDate
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FNames) 
        basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 1).Value = _
           mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("D1").Value 
        basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 2).Value = _
           mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("G1").Value 
        basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 3).Value = _
           mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C5").Value 
        basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 4).Value = _
           mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C8").Value 
        basebook.Worksheets(1).Cells(rnum, 5).Value = _
           mybook.Worksheets(1).Range("C9").Value 
        mybook.Close False 
        End If
        rnum = rnum + 1 
        FNames = Dir() 
    Loop
```